# Should the site get a facelift?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently, well, maybe not too recently, we saw the Ubuntu homepage get a new look. Linked [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com) I'm also throwing an image below comparing the two if you don't want to go through the trouble of getting to the actual site.

[image: Screenshot]

Image is a little small, but essentially they removes the lines in the title bar, moved some icons, and re-named some menus. Gave everything a softer feel.

In short, it looks like we're a little behind the times. Not too big of a change, but [OMG!Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/ubuntu-website-gets-subtle-revamp) covered the revamp not too long ago.

Is it time for a website upgrade to follow the previous theme of: We look like the Ubuntu website? Or should we keep what's familiar?

Comment: It's underway, according to Jin. Patience.

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't heard anything after searching around and after a look in the FAQ, I decided to throw something here.

Comment: Yeh, I think he only said that on the chat. [Here we go](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/redesign).

Comment: Should I get rid of the question then since we really don't need it?

Comment: Nah. Keep it. We could use it to have Jin respond with a list of changes or whatever.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Yes.

And I have decided to take some initiative. Presenting...

[image]

It's still a work in progress, but it makes a huge difference if you ask me. Want to give it a try? Of course you do!

I have packaged the whole thing up as a UserScript which you can install here:

> http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/autheme/au_theme.user.js

Feedback is welcome!

Comment: Wow! I love that!

Comment: Perfect. Seamless to [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com/) website

Comment: I don't like that the top bar is so fluid when the rest of the site isn't. Ubuntu.com doesn't have a fluid top car and neither should Ask Ubuntu (considering both layouts are fixed)

Comment: +1 because ,now ask question button is more visible. Ie it will solve well known usability bug

Comment: @Nathan Osman, Where can I provide the usage feedback?

Comment: @saji89: Right here is fine.

Comment: Just looking at the picture, the search bar could be incorporated into the orange bar (to the left of the 'Ask Question' button?) for EVEN MOAR consistency.

Comment: @Ads20000 I think it's better the way it is. We already need the white bar for the Global inbox and username, and I think it would look weird having the search bar next to the ask question button..

Comment: Very nice @NathanOsman! The script (run through GreaseMonkey on Firefox) is tremendous. Could use a little tweaking here and there, but overall I love it! Hope they at least take a little bit of an idea from your work!