# Upcoming site design changes

Tags: discussion, design

A few weeks ago Canonical reached out to me about making some design changes on Ask Ubuntu to reflect the official Ubuntu site's new design guidelines. The goal is to keep all Ubuntu related sites(official or 3rd party) consistent.

Currently on http://www.ubuntu.com, Ask Ubuntu is linked in the top nav bar under "More->Ask." Once the design changes are completed it will be prominently featured in the top bar.

Here's a preview of the new design:

[image: Ask Ubuntu New]

The biggest changes are in the header section. I moved "Ask Question" link to be part of the top nav bar. I Also removed the background images and widened the site content width by 20px.

The new design changes will go out early next week. The changes will take place both on the main site and Meta.

Comment: Bummer to lose the nice aubergine header under the main bar, I thought it was very slick. +1 to consistency though. And great to see askubuntu.com featured so prominently across all the ubuntu.com sites!

Comment: Love the space gained from removing the aubergine bar. My netbook will be able to display a question in addition - great job!

Comment: Why the white background? Its too bright for me.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam, "The Ubuntu colour palette has been created to reflect the spirit of our brand. Orange for a community feel. White for a clean, fresh and light feel. Cool grey is used for body copy." from http://design.ubuntu.com/web/colour. I change white to grey using css ;)

Comment: Oh, and this also: "#FFF and #EFEFEF: These colours are used as background colour to bring clarity, honesty and transparency to the design." LOL

Comment: @JorgeCastro I filed RT #22017 to have ask.ubuntu.com forward here. Renaming askubuntu.com to ask.ubuntu.com would need a lot more coordination.

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6709/should-the-site-get-a-facelift

Comment: If we're trying to adopt the styling of the homepage, we should probably drop the dotted background image.

Comment: @andrewsomething do you know if that's the new standard? Looking at unbuntu, [some pages](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/) have the dotted background still.

Comment: @Jin I can't seem to find a canonical statement (heh) about whether the dots are gone for good. Maybe jorge-castro could point you to someone n the design team. That said, I believe the the look of the main ubuntu.com page is slowly being rolled out everywhere. They're working with a lot of different stuff (Wordpress, Django, and more), so it might be taking more time on some platforms.

Comment: Everything looks good. Only thing I wish for is a little dark background for `code` tag as it was earlier. Here in meta site the "code" background is little dark but not in main site.

Comment: I mean <code> tag background is not #E0E0E0 anymore.. it is #F4F4F4 which is barely visible.

Comment: Why no change in mobile ui?

Comment: @Tachyons Mobile UI uses one clean theme per-network.

Answer (score 17):

It looks great! the one thing that really bugs me, is the footer:

[image: askubuntu-footer.png]

There is no background! And the dots are really annoying!

by adding some custom css to the `footerwrap` it looks a lot beter

```
.footerwrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #AAAAAA;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 970px;
}
```

[image: askubuntu-footer.png]

Comment: I agree. It's super difficult to read the links there. Your change looks much better.

Comment: I may remove the dots very soon.

Comment: @Jin i use a line on my website, and did the same on askubuntu. Here is the result: http://i.imgur.com/BpGcg8d.png

Comment: @blade19899 That would be perfect! What is the license of your design? (the `line.png` file)

Comment: @Lucio After some time tracking down where I got the `line.png` I found out that I saw it once on webupd8.org. It has a license of http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/ro/deed.en But i don't know if that includes such a small portion of webupd8.org such as a line image. I myself was thinking of the same license (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/) for my website.

Comment: @blade19899 Thanks for the reply. Personally, I prefer to use [this license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.en_US). It is more **free** than the *non-commercial* one. Just an opinion..

Answer (score 11):

So, I just wanted to drop by and leave some feedback on the new topbar design.

First of all, thanks for the addition, it is quite handy however there is also something that's bugging me about it.

The bottom margin of the new topbar makes the entire design look out of place. My suggestion would be to remove the 22 pixels.

Here's a screenshot from the current setup,

[image]

and here is a screenshot but without the 22 pixels bottom margin,

[image]

Comment: I personally like the extra 20 or so pixels there. It helps separate the site from the Canonical/Ubuntu header which isn't present on any other SE sites.

Comment: @Seth While it's true that no other SE site has that header, you should look at it in context. No other website in that bar has a 20 pixel margin. It looks completely out of place.

Comment: It looks worse without the margin though.

Answer (score 9):

It came live as I changed pages... great design.

**Edit *(after 24 hours)***

It took me by surprise, and I still, after 24 hours go to the very top of the page to check is I have any comment alerts.

On the whole a much cleaner look

**Thumbs Up** * * * * *

**Edit *(after 2 weeks)***

Still love the new design. I have had to go into the browser config files to change the code background/pre colour to one that I can see. but that's my only complaint

Still **Thumbs Up** * * * * *

Answer (score 9):

To remove the dotted grid like effect on Ask Ubuntu, block `http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntu/img/bg-site.png`. You may have to flush your browser's cache to see the effect.

For the meta site, block `http://cdn.sstatic.net/askubuntumeta/img/bg-site.png`.

For example:

[image: Imgur]

---

To minimize the space between the global menu and the main section, the following code is useful:

```
#custom-header {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}
```

This code needs to go into a stylesheet. If one is using Firefox, this can be done by editing `userContent.css` which is located in `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/chrome`. If the folder `chrome` doesn't exist, just create it. Same for `userContent.css`. Both folder and filename are case-sensitive.

Then, in userContent.css, add the following using a plain text editor:

```
@namespace html url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain(askubuntu.com) 
{ 
#custom-header {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}
}
```

and save the file and exit. The value for `margin-bottom` determines the space between the `global menu` and the `main section`. The default (currently) is 22px. I've reduced it to 2px as an example.

Note: if one using the Stylish extension, one can use "Write new style ..." for askubuntu.com and paste just

```
#custom-header {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 2px !important;
}
```

between the existing curly brackets.

(Stylish works for Chrome/Chromium as well.)

[image: Imgur]

---

To make **code** more visible, one can make the code font bold, darker, or use a background which may enhance contrast:

Consider something like this:

```
@namespace html url(w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain(askubuntu.com)
{
code { 
      font-family: monospace !important; 
      color: black !important; 
      background-color: #999 !important; 
      font-weight: bold !important; }
}
```

The line with `monospace` makes sure code remains fixed and not proportional (which would mess up alignment);
The line with `color` determines the font color. It can be any html color you like; you can use hex code to get exactly the color you want by using a tool such as `gcolor2` from the software center;
The line with `background-color` lets you enhance contrast by that route if you wish;
The line with `font-weight` makes text bold.

You can use one or all of the above.

Note that in `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxx.default/chrome`, the `xxxx` will differ from user to user.

Comment: To improve the code readability, I have background-color set as `#ccc` without setting the font-weight as bold, and find that seems to be the best compromise.

Answer (score 8):

I like the new design, but I have some observations:

- there is a problem with some special characters (see my name):

[image]

- the new background for code sample make that a code text to be difficult to distinguish towards the normal text:

[image][image]

Comment: I noticed the code formatting change as well, and I also don't like it.

Comment: Background in code block is nearly-white, that I think is bare to see.

Comment: And that code block BG color is different on `meta`

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the `Add Comment` button could do with some `margin` to separate it from the comment `textarea`.
[image: Add Comment button]

***Update:***
This has now been fixed:
[image: Add comment fixed]

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the header to be consistent with Stack Exchange than with Ubuntu, so I removed the Ubuntu header [with Stylish](https://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser/465964#465964).

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("askubuntu.com") {
    div#custom-header {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoting for technical merit (though I don't mind the header).

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Should this logo given `meta` label? Like "Ask Ubuntu Meta" or "Meta Ask Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 4):

New design is now live. Looking good.

Can we make the `Ask Question` button more distinguised. 
A possible way will be to use a mildly darker red background for it. I'm not a designer, there might be better ways for it.

[image: Askubuntu New Design]

Comment: It's funny, every design iteration everyone asks to make the Ask button more distinguished. They asked to move Ask from below the nav on the aubergine to the top nav, now it's in the top nav and it's not good enough ;) I think people will find the button, it's even more obvious to users who aren't logged in.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi, In every iteration this button is pointed out because for `ask`ubuntu site, the `Ask Question` button should be given due focus, with ease for newcomers also in mind.. :)

Comment: Try visiting the site not logged in (Incognito) to see the new user experience. The "[tour](http://askubuntu.com/about)" is pushed onto them and gives them a low down of the site. Given that we're getting over 120 questions an hour I don't think people are having a hard time finding that button :)

Answer (score 4):

I love the new layout but... (sorry there has to be a but). Now that Ask is so integrated into the Ubuntu site, is there now the danger that new users (especially) will consider it to be some kind of official Ubuntu tech support as opposed to the community driven Q & A it actually is.

If they were to have this false impression it could lead to situations where a user becomes more impatient when an answer is not immediately forthcoming or they fail to realise that an answer could conceivably be wrong.

I am aware that there is plenty of documentation that explains what Ask is, but many of the new users I have come across have clearly not taken the time to understand this. They just want an answer then never to be seen again!

Comment: There's really no such thing as "official tech support"; help.u.c, the forums, launchpad, IRC, and AU are all community driven.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Seems that button missed 'few' pixels to align...

Comment: I never noticed that before. You have a good eye.

Comment: Recognized even with normal size (100%)

Answer (score 3):

The `Tell me more` button in non logged-in display of a question page seems to be a bit too big, that it overflows out of the containing `div`.
[image: Tell Me more]

***Update:***
This has now been fixed:

[image: Tell me more button fixed]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Way too big for buttons...

Answer (score 2):

Albit annoying...

[image: before hover]

[image: after hover]

Also in meta site.

Answer (score 2):

No `box-shadow` in `.container`

## before:

[image]

## After:

[image]

### Code

```
.container {
    .....
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #aaa;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The background of the entire site looks distracting, plus there have been users complaining about the tearing of it. When I press <kbd>SUPER</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>, the background image, just annoys my eyes. Not a good look.

Screenshots

**ONE**

[image: ONE]

**TWO**

[image: TWO]

The entire code:

```
body {
    background: #f9f9f9 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.topbar {
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);
}


#header {
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);
}


#content {
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);
}


#footer .footerwrap {
    box-shadow: 1px -1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the visuals in the current design create a feeling of information overload for me. I'd make [a few small changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAPaK.png) to help direct readers' attention to the content. Here's [the current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuV8U.png) for comparison.

Comment: I personally like the extra 20 or so pixels there. It helps separate the site from the Canonical/Ubuntu header which isn't present on any other SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

The stars that users can click to mark "Favorite" should be changed to Ubuntu's red circular symbol or this awesome symbol http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~devyncjohnson-d/misc-projects/trunk/view/head:/Symbols/Ubuntu_Shiny_Remix.png. The badges should also look like the Ubuntu symbol.

Answer (score 1):

blockquote design change. IMHO, it definitely needs a new design:

## blockquote design 1

[image]

### code

```
blockquote {
    .....
    border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    .....
}
```

## blockquote design 2

[image]

### code

```
blockquote {
    .....
    border-left: 5px solid #CCCCCC;
    .....
}
```

I find it better for my eyes to focus, with the borders!

Answer (score 0):

Seems annoying if didn't aligned...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Misaligned again...

Answer (score 0):

## code(pre) design:

[image]

### code

```
pre {
    .....
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    .....
}
```

IMO: it reads better with the borders!

Comment: It had borders before? I think that looks ugly :-P

Comment: @Seth, nope. I just like it better with the borders, `blockquote` and `pre`.