# Is there an option to remove the bar above the status bar?

Tags: support, design, user-interface

There is a new bar above the "status bar" with Ubuntu/Community/Development/Ask.
This is new and I feel it is taking up valuable screen space, since I do not plan on regularly using the new links.

I have used Ad Blocker to remove it but that seems overkill. Is there an option to change this, or hide it so the status bar is on top like the other Stackexchange sites?

Comment: Now how about we turn down the hostility a bit, hm?

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6788/upcoming-site-design-changes

Comment: @FEichinger Wasn't meant to be hostile, apology if it sounded that way, guess I will stick to AD blocker. Just asking :)

Comment: See http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6811/25656 for another way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible, looks like they modified the site layout. But you can send a feedback saying that you'd like to a button to activate and deactivate the top bar.

Comment: Yes, I did think that as the very bright orange header did startled me this morning, I doubt my voice would make a difference. But thank you for confirming the site change, although its odd that they would depart from the rest of the Stack web sites in such a major way. I think I will pull out my Tamper Monkey ;)

Comment: @MeerBorg It matches the identity and branding of http://ubuntu.com

Comment: Perhaps a ^ on the Right to hide this bar may be an idea to consider in the future, with an open link to show it again

Comment: @MeerBorg You don't have to think about it as something bad, if look from another perspective, this header will attract new user to our community, because everyone that is using a service related with Ubuntu will see that header and a cool thing on it labeled Ask!

Answer (score 2):

There's no option, but you can instruct your browser to do it. Install the Stylish extension ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)). In Firefox, you can use this code:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("askubuntu.com") {
    div#custom-header {
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```

In Chrome, enter the following code, and specify that it applies to “URLs on the domain” `askubuntu.com`.

```
div#custom-header {
    display:none !important;
}
```

<sub>[Everything you ever wanted to know about custom CSS](https://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser/465964#465964)</sub>