# Code formatting from new site design changes simply annoys me

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design

The new background for a code sample makes that this to be difficult to distinguish towards a normal text:

---

[image][image]

---

Maybe for some screens it's ok, but not for the majority. Many times I have to change the screen position or my head position to distinguish a code sample and I don't think this is normal. Is there any chance to revert this to the previous state?

Comment: I like the idea of a sample cod.

Comment: The lighter background also makes it harder to differentiate between code blocks and blockquotes which could further encourage the misuse of the latter.

Comment: Oh, and another thing: The new fonts look a bit fuzzy to me when they are **bold** or *italic*.

Comment: I think that subtle differences are favored **across** SE sites and elsewhere too. I don't see the reason for this. I just fix things for myself using css.

Comment: @vasa1 How did you fix using css? I think that you can post as answer.

Comment: I already posted here: http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6817/25656

Comment: @vasa1 Oh, yes, but I'm using Chromium browser

Comment: Have you installed the Stylish extension (ID: fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) from the Chrome Web Store? That allows you to do per site customizations even with Chromium.

Comment: If you don't want to install an extension, you can still make `code` look the way you want. Go into `~/.config/chrome/Default/User\ Stylesheets`. In there, you should find Custom.css. Edit that file by adding the following: `code { background-color: #bbb !important; }`. That's it. Now all code on any web page, not just Ask Ubuntu, will have a light grey background. As I posted elsewhere, you can choose to even give code text a color of your choice. The advantage of the Stylish extension is that you can style different pages differently. Stylish also lets you disable a style temporarily.

Comment: Ok, I've done it; `code { background-color: #ddd !important; } blockquote { background-color: #ddd !important; } pre{ background-color: #ddd !important; }` looks like before. Thank you! But still  I'm not happy with this kind of solutions...

Comment: You can shorten that to `blockquote, code, pre { background-color: #ddd !important; }`.

Comment: Seriously guys, if this is a usability issue it should *not* be solved with browser add-ons. The design should be adapted. There is not shame in that.

Comment: I though it was me! I know my eyes were bad, but there is hardly any difference between the code background and the ordinary background. A simple style issue. I like the layout except for the location bar along the top. Why not make this collapsible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree and I think we should rollback to the css styles used for the code blocks in the previous design.

If this is a usability or user interface issue, then browser add-ons to change the css locally are not the answer.

Think about all the new users, first time visitors, etc.

Answer (score 4):

The actual lay out is good, except for the locations bar along the top (make it collapsible) also darken the code background to how it was before to accomodate my failing eyes.

I would like to see, in the future, in settings an option to change the background colours to whatever you want it to be.

I have, for instance, changed mine to be more obvious

[image]