# How do I disable the background on the site? It kills my Dell monitor!

Tags: discussion, design

I've recently bought a Dell UltraSharp U2713HM and it really cannot handle the pattern of dots in the background of Ask Ubuntu (main). I'm asking it here on AU meta, because it concerns the site design (and see below).

After a few minutes having the site at full screen it starts to flicker at about 10Hz and it's unstoppable. It does not stop until I have run a full LCD recalibration for a few hours while in the meantime I cannot use it. It will already trigger if it's just a few hundreds of pixels of a stroke of it being displayed, but fullscreen is really killing.

Yes, I know this is a bug in the hardware of my monitor. And yes, it's silly. And of course I should return it for warranty, but I don't think a new one of the same type will fix this.

So, how could I create a

- userscript,
- custom CSS, or
- *whatever*

in both **Google Chrome** and **Firefox** to just get me a plain fill background on AU?

<sub>Note: I know this is not really a [discussion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/discussion) question, but I had to select one of them and this is not really the task of SE staff to handle.</sub>

Comment: Sort of duplicate ... the answer is here (http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6817/14356)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a script in userscripts similar to what you are asking: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/172460

Works perfectly with greasemonkey in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: "I found a script". Yeah right. It points to "The power of gertvdijk". Now I feel delighted. Let me have a look. :) It's awesome.

Comment: @gertvdijk Let me know if it helps, I will personally slap the developer until he changes the code.

Comment: *Personally* slap the developer? O_o

Comment: @Seth Ever played Dungeon Keeper ^^. That's how you get the job done.

Comment: It is awesome. Sometimes the backgroud re-appears when using the flagging dialogue, though. Not sure why.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado, great little script! Are you an expert in this? I've played with [zap white backgrounds](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/zap.html) a bit as a bookmarklet but this is so much better in that the bookmarklet has to be run on a per-page basis. Could you combine the two to make a script that would make the background of Ask Ubuntu completely another color (not white but #999 for example)? Currently, your script only affects part of the page. (In case it isn't clear, I know nothing about scripts!)

Comment: Forgot to mention that the specific script is called "zap white backgrounds" in the bookmarklets column.

Comment: Sorry guys, just noticing this at 2:30 am here. Today (Afternoon) Ill make another... I mean, the developer will make some changes. He told me so.

Comment: Thanks to this QnA, I rediscovered http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/62388 which is a script based on the "zap white backgrounds" bookmarklet.