# Background with dots gives unpleasant effects on scroll

Tags: bug, design

Most LCD monitors [have problems](http://www.techmind.org/lcd/) displaying [regular](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12151/why-do-some-patterns-flicker-in-strange-colors-while-scrolling) patterns of dots (or lines). I've tried several LCDs, and on each of them dots in background of `askubuntu` flicker badly. That's why it's a bad idea to use them in a design. This issue was described at least twice:

["<display> cannot handle the pattern of dots"](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6979/how-do-i-disable-the-background-on-the-site-it-kills-my-dell-monitor)

["dotted backgrounds are really unfriendly to my eyes"](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/499/226321)

Could we fix this, please?

UPD. I'm not interested in monkey patches like in the question someone told this is a duplicate of. I wish this was solved properly. I need no advice on Greasemonkey or Adblock.

Comment: It sounds like you have a valid point but since I don't have an LCD screen, it's hard to understand how bad it is for you. Do you think you could include a short gif or even link to a video demonstrating the issue?

Comment: It's not a problem on my screen, but I think we should take folks' word for it if they say it's eye-hurting...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the background on the site? It kills my Dell monitor!](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6979/how-do-i-disable-the-background-on-the-site-it-kills-my-dell-monitor)

Comment: @Mateo Nope, not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this too, on pretty much every computer I've used with this site. It seems to be worse on Ubuntu than Windows, which is somewhat ironic.

I personally think it would be nice to get rid of the texture altogether. It's an image file set to repeat, so it's just more resources to load a texture that doesn't look that great, even if it doesn't cause the distortion issue.

Right now, my `se-dark` user script just completely removes the textured background, and it doesn't seem to take away from the design of the site at all. In fact, I found it somewhat disruptive.

I hope it'll get removed, but in the meantime, I can make a very simple userscript for Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey that'll do nothing else but remove the dots. Tell me if you'd like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it in the background here. Perhaps this is a problem with your system or your screen as noted in the first link you provided  LCD screens "do not normally flicker". I do however see it in the graph you posted in the second link. This could also have something to do with the theme you've chosen using a background fill to obtain a given color or shade thereof that's causing you issues. My theme is "Ambiance" (the default) I propose that you try that, and believe your results would mirror mine and this issue would be as resolved for you as it is for me. (I honestly originally thought this question was mis-posted here and was meant for the main site as I couldn't replicate your problem with the background here).

Comment: What kind of a theme? It's default CSS of `askubuntu`. It's http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/askubuntu/img/bg-site.png in background of a <body>.

Comment: This issue is visible on a display with sRGB color space set. Probably with default improper color space these dots are invisible.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph It would be interesting to find out for sure.